# Where is the temporary directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, temporary-files

Does Linux have a standard temporary directory for general use, like Windows's `C:\Temp` folder? If so, where is it located? I found [an SO question about finding a `tmp` directory programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068/how-do-i-find-the-temp-directory-in-linux), but I want to set a temp location in an XML config file ahead of time.

Comment: I know this looks like a really easy question, but I couldn't find a clear, simple answer through searching. Many of the results I got were for program-specific temp directories/files. I did see multiple references to `/tmp`, but they were ambiguous about whether that's standard for Linux or just a common convention.

Comment: Windows's `C:\Temp` is most certainly *not* standard. Windows 95 already had `%TEMP%` pointing to `C:\WINDOWS\Temp`.

Comment: If you have PHP running: `sys_get_temp_dir();`

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml) version 3.0 says:

> ##### [/tmp : Temporary files](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s18.html)
>
> The `/tmp` directory must be made available for programs that require
> temporary files.
>
> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in `/tmp` are
> preserved between invocations of the program.
>
> ###### Rationale
>
> IEEE standard POSIX.1-2008 lists requirements similar to the above section.
> Although data stored in `/tmp` may be deleted in a site-specific manner, it
> is recommended that files and directories located in `/tmp` be deleted
> whenever the system is booted.
>
> FHS added this recommendation on the basis of historical precedent and common
> practice, but did not make it a requirement because system administration is
> not within the scope of this standard.
>
> ##### [/var/tmp : Temporary files preserved between system reboots](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s15.html)
>
> The `/var/tmp` directory is made available for programs that require
> temporary files or directories that are preserved between system
> reboots. Therefore, data stored in `/var/tmp` is more persistent than
> data in `/tmp`.
>
> Files and directories located in `/var/tmp` must not be deleted when the
> system is booted. Although data stored in `/var/tmp` is typically
> deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that deletions
> occur at a less frequent interval than `/tmp`.

Also the [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, Environment Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) mentions the following:

> `TMPDIR`
> This variable shall represent a pathname of a directory made available for programs that need a place to create temporary files.

[systemd](https://systemd.io/TEMPORARY_DIRECTORIES/) has a say on this too:

> [`/tmp/`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#/tmp/) and [`/var/tmp/`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#/var/tmp/) are two world-writable directories Linux systems provide for temporary files. The former is typically on *tmpfs* and thus backed by RAM/swap, and flushed out on each reboot. The latter is typically a proper, persistent file system, and thus backed by physical storage. This means:
>
> 1. `/tmp/` should be used for smaller, size-bounded files only; `/var/tmp/` should be used for everything else.
> 2. Data that shall survive a boot cycle shouldn’t be placed in `/tmp/`.
>
> If the `$TMPDIR` environment variable is set, use that path, and neither use `/tmp/` nor `/var/tmp/` directly.
>
> See [file-hierarchy(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html) for details about these two (and most other) directories of a Linux system.

The paths can be queried with [**systemd-path**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-path.html):

```
$ systemd-path temporary
/tmp
$ systemd-path temporary-large
/var/tmp
```

---

[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&sektion=7), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/hier.7), [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/hier.7) and [DragonFly](https://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=hier&section=7) have something similar described in the **hier(7)** man page.

Answer (score 19):

This is an old question so today there is another option available. Linux distributions relying on `systemd` (which is 90% of them) can now use `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` directory ([XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)) to store certain types of temporary files. It is generally located at `/run/user/$uid`.

- This is a per-user directory with `700` - keeping files private
- This is a `tmpfs` mount (aka RAM drive) with great performance
- It gets cleaned up automatically

The downside of `tmpfs` is that it should only be used to store small files (PID files, lock files, sockets etc).

Comment: On current systemd based Linux distributions, [`/var/run`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#/var/run/) is a compatibility symlink pointing to `/run`.

Answer (score 11):

Yes /tmp is for general use. See [here](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) On the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard.

> /tmp/  Temporary files (see also /var/tmp). Often not preserved between system reboots.

With some more details listed in the PDF.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot choose a single temporary directory name ahead of time that will work for any Linux system. In fact, you can't do that on Windows either. According to Wikipedia's [article on temporary folders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_folder), the temporary directory on Windows is determined by the environment variable TEMP. If you were simply using `c:\Temp` as a temporary directory on a Windows system that set TEMP to something else, then any program using your XML file to choose a temporary directory would fail.

In short, the system temporary directory is determined by the environment on all modern operating systems that I know of, including both Windows and any UNIX-like system. Setting a single static path as your temporary directory will only work as long as the defaults have not been changed.

Anyway, the standard temporary directory in a typical Linux system is `/tmp`. It is the equivalent of `C:\Temp` in the sense that it is *only* the default temporary directory, not universal. Even if `/tmp` is available, if a user (or the system) has set the TEMP environment variable, the value of that variable should be used instead.

You could try choosing a temporary directory relative to the user's home directory, which you can create.

Comment: Some programs like bash, gcc, inkscape or lynx use the `TMPDIR` environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

The initial question was: Does Linux have a standard temporary directory. If so, where is it located?
The tmp folder(s) are found at: File System/tmp & 
                                File System/var/tmp
The /tmp contents could be deleted - if you know which files/folders are required/not required by various apps on an "as required" basis. Unrequired files are usually those downloaded by an app to facilitate the app itself at that point only- therefore not further required after the app has performed. 
The /var/tmp folder should not be touched at all.

Comment: This answer does not provide more information than the accepted answer, so it is quite useless.